# Upgrade MySQL 5.5 to 5.6 on Ubuntu 12.04 LTS

Tags: 12.04, upgrade, mysql

I'm trying to upgrade MySQL 5.5 to version 5.6 on my Ubuntu 12.04 LTS server. I've tried the following:

```
apt-get -y remove mysql-server
apt-get -y autoremove
apt-get -y install software-properties-common
add-apt-repository -y ppa:ondrej/mysql-5.6
apt-get update
apt-get -y install mysql-server
```

When I try this, I'm still left with version 5.5. Is there no simple way of upgrading in 12.04? Seriously need it for Magento 2! :(

Comment: The PPA ppa:ondrej/mysql-5.6 doesn't have any packages for Ubuntu 12.04.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I go to https://launchpad.net/~ondrej/+archive/ubuntu/mysql-5.6 I can see clearly that the package you're interested in is named `mysql-5.6`. So you could go ahead and

```
sudo apt-get install mysql-5.6
```

Packages from 3rd party repos don't have to follow the same naming convention as Ubuntu repos.

But as [@Florian Diesch](https://askubuntu.com/users/2369/florian-diesch) noticed, there are no packages for your Ubuntu version in that repo.

Comment: I guess I'll scrap that and look at upgrading my VPS then!